# Список товаров одном заказе

Tags: er-diagram, sql, mysql

Делаю БД заказа товара. Есть таблица товары и таблица заказ.
Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы было в одном заказе много различных товаров с разным количеством? 
[image: ERR diagram]

**UPDATE**

Comment: @depredator, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В `order_products` **перенести** `quantity` из `products`, а также **скопировать** `price`. При добавлении товара в заказ цена копируется в детали заказа.

ЗЫ У вас `material` два раза в `products`.

Comment: сделал, но все равно как я смогу узнать, что в одном заказе у меня 4 разных товара

Comment: Натурально

    select id_products, quantity, price, quantity*price as summ
    from orders_products where id_orders = 47

выведутся все товары заказа с id=47.

Comment: Еще хочу спросить, в общем, делаю систему учета закупок деталей. Необходимо, к примеру, купить деталь к чему-то (деталь для такого-то оборудывания). Есть таблица оборудываний. Один товар может закупатся для одного оборудывания или для всех. Насколько я понимаю, у меня будет связь один ко многим. Понадобится дополнительная таблица. Только не пойму, как мне связивать (по какой таблици). Я предполагаю по id_products и id_оборудывания. То есть все это должно так выглядить: Заказ №122 == Товар №1, к-во, цена, машина №2 (куда заказываем); Товар 2, к-во, цена, машина №5;
Все это как один заказ идет.

Comment: @depredator, сложно что-либо советовать, не зная всей задачи. По описанию достаточно просто поля в order_products. Какие-либо особенные связи не нужны.